# Получение JSON с внешнего ресурса Андроид

Tags: android, json

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста как можно получить с сайта (например: http://androiddocs.ru/api/friends.json) и распарсить json в андроид. Из интернета перепробовал многое, но толком ничего не получилось. Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Ну а чем этот пример вам не подходит? [Парсинг JSON](http://androiddocs.ru/parsing-json-poluchaem-i-razbiraem-json-s-vneshnego-resursa/)

Comment: проект вылетает

Comment: А у Вас этот проект работает?

Лог:
12-20 14:00:11.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1137): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 14:00:11.548: E/AndroidRuntime(1137): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{by.slowar.androidtest/by.slowar.androidtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "by.slowar.androidtest.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/by.slowar.androidtest-2.apk

Скриншот:
http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=ac4e0a96cb7300e47b07170472373fc1

Comment: скорее всего в манифесте не прописан класс MainActivity, вот он его и не находит

Comment: вот именно, что он есть:http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=aa08bc0f1a5a1ce39c2eb1b9c04c093e
А у Вас этот проект работает?

Comment: Да, я его просто скопипастил в новый проект и все

Comment: Попробовал создать новый проект с другими именами, также не работает. Я полностью копирую MainActivity, activity_main, и разрешение в манифест, версии апи от 8 до 19. Вроде все действия описал. Может что забыл? Еще добавляю две библиотеки: android-support-v4.jar и android-support-v7.jar

Comment: a package вы случайно не меняете в MainActivity ?

Comment: ссылка протухла. Ответ не имеет смысла

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался: в MainActivity поменял extends ActionBarActivity на extends Activity. Bondar Stanislav, спасибо за помощь и внимание